# Showing a list of only filenames while having full file paths connected

Tags: java, list, file, javafx, filenames

I would like to be able to display a list of files showing only the file name not the whole file path.

Currently I have a list of files. When I click one of these files the listener passes this to a method out of scope which loads the file.

This means if I was to just pass it a list of just file names it would no longer work as my listener requires a full file path. I do not have any ideas as to how I would go about both storing a list of filenames whilst simultaneously linking them to the full file path.

Happy to answer any questions you may have. Many thanks,

Note: the small for loop shows how I could potentially extract the filename from the file path, but I am not currently doing anything with it at this time. It's just an example to show you how far I have gotten.

```
public void GetFilesFromFolder(String dirName) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File(dirName);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles((File dir1, String filename) -> filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
        String[] fileName = new String[files.length];
        int x = 0;
        for (File file : files) {
            String fileTemp = file.toString();
            fileTemp = fileTemp.substring(fileTemp.lastIndexOf("\\" + 1));
            System.out.println(fileTemp);
            fileName[x] = fileTemp;
            System.out.println(fileName[x]);
            x++;
        }
        observableList.clear();
        observableList.addAll(files);
    }

    public void SetFileListView() throws IOException {
        listView.setItems(null);
    }

    public VBox listStack() throws IOException {
        vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(listView);

        listView.setItems(observableList);
        listView.setMinHeight(500);
        MusicDataModel mdm = MainView.getMainView().musicDataModel;
        MusicDataViewController mdv = MainView.getMainView().musicDataViewController;
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends File> observable, File oldValue, File newValue) -> {
            try {
                mdm.load(newValue.toString());
                mdv.SetValues();
            } catch (UnsupportedTagException | InvalidDataException | IOException | NotSupportedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileListView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
        return vbox;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate the list view with `File`s, as you currently do, and use a cell factory on the list view to change the way the file is displayed:

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<File>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(file, empty);
        setText(file == null ? null : file.getName());
    }
});
```

This will ensure each cell in the list view displays only the file name (the last component of the file's full path), though it still retains the `File` instance as its data (so you can still get the selected `File`, etc).

Comment: While this works really well and I'm grateful it now slows down when I click on an item in the list, can you hazard a guess as to what may be causing it. I assume it's likely regenerating something.

Comment: No clue. That's more likely to be to do with your listener code than the custom cell. The `updateItem(...)` method is invoked very frequently, e.g. if you scroll, so if there were performance issues there you would see them at times other than selecting an item.